# how to select and copy some text when i right click on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a text on my html page.

When I select and right click on text, i have to copy that text and want to show 
in another popup or want to load another window with selected text.

Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I am trying on java script within user computer

Comment: What code have you already tried? Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

> You cannot really know what is in the clipboard of a user unless you used some sort of flash backend when they copied the text.

---

However `window.clipboardData.getData` will work in some browsers.

```
var text = window.clipboardData.getData('Text');
alert(text); //Popup with copied text.
```

---

Automatic copying to clipboard may be dangerous, therefore most browsers (except IE) make it very difficult. But you could use this simple trick:

```
function copyToClipboard(text) {
  window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
}
```

The user is presented with the prompt box, where the text to be copied is already selected. Now it's enough to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> (to close the box) -- and voila!

You can do this because the user does it manually (but in a pretty straightforward way). Of course, works in all browsers.

Comment: great answer! I like how you bypass the security :)